# How to solve ssl certificate error with GetX and Get Connect in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, https, response, flutter-getx

I am trying to use Getx service.

here is my api client class as am trying to get data from internet using getx

```
import 'package:flutter_application_shop/utilis/app_constance.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  late String token;
  final String appBaseUrl;
  late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders;

  ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl}) {
    baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
    timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    token = AppConstance.TOKEN;

    _mainHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }

  Future<Response> getData(String url) async {
    try {
      Response response = await get(url);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }

  ///end
}
```

and when I run debug, I get this error.

```
I/flutter ( 6967): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
I/flutter ( 6967):      CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:393))
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the request is coming from an untrusted source, in order to bypass the error, Add `allowAutoSignedCert = true;` to your request in the class that extends `GetConnet`.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter_application_shop/utilis/app_constance.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ApiClient extends GetConnect implements GetxService {
  late String token;
  final String appBaseUrl;
  late Map<String, String> _mainHeaders;

  ApiClient({required this.appBaseUrl}) {
    baseUrl = appBaseUrl;
    timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    token = AppConstance.TOKEN;
    allowAutoSignedCert = true; // the solution

    _mainHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    };
  }

  Future<Response> getData(String url) async {
    try {
      Response response = await get(url);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where `allowAutoSignedCert = true;` was working on ios but not on android and the on init method for the class which extends GetConnect was as follows.

```
class BaseProvider extends GetConnect {
@override
void onInit() {
super.onInit();
httpClient.baseUrl = ApiConstants.baseUrl;
httpClient.timeout = ApiConstants.timeOutInSeconds;
allowAutoSignedCert = true;
 }
}
```

By moving the `allowAutoSignedCert = true;` to the top of my onInit() method the allowAutoSignedCert started to work as expected:

```
class BaseProvider extends GetConnect {
@override
void onInit() {
allowAutoSignedCert = true; //Moved to top
super.onInit();
httpClient.baseUrl = ApiConstants.baseUrl;
httpClient.timeout = ApiConstants.timeOutInSeconds;
 }
}
```